# Magento 2 payment Checkout page keep showing loader

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, payment-methods

Magento 2 payment Checkout page keep showing loader. without showing any error on console or in terminal.[image: Checkout Page]

[image]

Comment: Can you show your var/log/exception.log file?

Comment: Did you check with default theme?

Answer (score -1):

It's because none of the payment options will be enabled by default. You can enable with Stores->configuration-> Sales->Payment Methods-> Cash On Delivery Payment. 
[image]
 So for testing purpose, you can enable 'Cash on Delivery' option from admin panel. 
Flush the cache and then try again.

Comment: Thanx for reply Pavan , But i have to reinstall the magento setup again to solve this mystery.

Comment: why do u need to reinstall?? i don tunderstand

Comment: i don't understand the exact problem either that's why  i have to.

Comment: This is the only problem. I had faced teh same. If u havent yet started the reinstallation, stop it and check on this once. Ofcourse, if you reinstall also you will face the same issue.

Comment: No didn't get any issue after fresh install.

Comment: -1 No payment method doesn't cause this problem, simply, the magento shows no payment method on payment step.

Answer (score -1):

If you have made changes in checkout file like override in your custom theme

```
Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

or inside

```
Magento_Checkout/templates/..
```

then keep it revert back it will work.

Comment: -1 This is not a answer, basically, he needs the way to fix not a way to revert.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but I think this is the solution for this particular case.

First of all check in console. A error might appear like,

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals::setExtensionAttributes() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsExtensionInterface, instance
>   of Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtension given, called in
>   /htdocs/magento2.2/vendor/magento/framework/Api/DataObjectHelper.php
>   on line 125 and defined in
>   /htdocs/magento2.2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Cart/Totals.php:592

I debugged for quite a while and come the following solution.

- Need to override **Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository**

For that, add following in Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Rewrite\Quote\CartTotalRepository" />
```

- Create CartTotalRepository.php at the path Namespace\Module\Model\Rewrite\Quote\CartTotalRepository.php

Paste the following code in CartTotalRepository.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Rewrite\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Api;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartTotalRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\ItemConverter;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface;

/*Added below two lines*/
use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\TotalsConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface;

/**
 * Cart totals data object.
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CartTotalRepository extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository
{
    /**
     * Cart totals factory.
     *
     * @var Api\Data\TotalsInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $totalsFactory;

    /**
     * Quote repository.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
     */
    private $dataObjectHelper;

    /**
     * @var ConfigurationPool
     */
    private $itemConverter;

    /**
     * @var CouponManagementInterface
     */
    protected $couponService;

    /**
     * @var TotalsConverter
     */
    protected $totalsConverter;

    /**
     * @param Api\Data\TotalsInterfaceFactory $totalsFactory
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param CouponManagementInterface $couponService
     * @param TotalsConverter $totalsConverter
     * @param ItemConverter $converter
     */
    public function __construct(
        Api\Data\TotalsInterfaceFactory $totalsFactory,
        CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        CouponManagementInterface $couponService,
        TotalsConverter $totalsConverter,
        ItemConverter $converter
    ) {
        $this->totalsFactory = $totalsFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        $this->couponService = $couponService;
        $this->totalsConverter = $totalsConverter;
        $this->itemConverter = $converter;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @param int $cartId The cart ID.
     * @return Totals Quote totals data.
     */
    public function get($cartId)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
            $addressTotalsData = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getData();
            $addressTotals = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getTotals();
        } else {
            $addressTotalsData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
            $addressTotals = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getTotals();
        }
        //Added New Line Here
        unset($addressTotalsData[ExtensibleDataInterface::EXTENSION_ATTRIBUTES_KEY]);
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface $quoteTotals */
        $quoteTotals = $this->totalsFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
            $quoteTotals,
            $addressTotalsData,
            \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface::class
        );
        $items = [];
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $index => $item) {
            $items[$index] = $this->itemConverter->modelToDataObject($item);
        }
        $calculatedTotals = $this->totalsConverter->process($addressTotals);
        $quoteTotals->setTotalSegments($calculatedTotals);

        $amount = $quoteTotals->getGrandTotal() - $quoteTotals->getTaxAmount();
        $amount = $amount > 0 ? $amount : 0;
        $quoteTotals->setCouponCode($this->couponService->get($cartId));
        $quoteTotals->setGrandTotal($amount);
        $quoteTotals->setItems($items);
        $quoteTotals->setItemsQty($quote->getItemsQty());
        $quoteTotals->setBaseCurrencyCode($quote->getBaseCurrencyCode());
        $quoteTotals->setQuoteCurrencyCode($quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode());
        return $quoteTotals;
    }
}
```

I have made 2 modifications in the file.
1. Simply added 2 lines on line number 17 & 18.
2. Added 1 line on line number 102.

Comment: -1 this answer doesn't related to the question.